# Computer shuts down randomly - suspected PSU or memory - which one is it?

Tags: memory, power-supply, shutdown

I have replaced the motherboard and CPU after the old motherboard has died. Now PC is shutting down randomly (it doesn't depend on what sort of software I am running - could be working fine with Adobe Premiere and shut down while not in use at all).

The memory sticks and PSU are still old ones from previous build.

The specs:

- Motherboard: asus Z79-ar
- CPU Intel Core i7
- PSU 750W
- 4x2gb corsair dominator-gt memory sticks

It seems to be working without shutting down with one memory stick in it. Shuts off with any two.

When it shuts down, sometimes it doesn't restart - only the fans are blowing and I need to switch it off and then on in ~30 seconds.

Heating is not the problem - checked it - all fine.

Since something has killed my previous motherboard, don't want it to happen again, but not sure which module is the faulty one - memory or PSU?

Comment: I had a similar case and ere the CPU was faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of the problem was in the faulty power supply, it consequently damaged first the mother board, then the RAM. After power supply was replaced, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sounds like ram issue if you say its still on without anything showing on screen. Try memtest and see what it says. Have you tried just using each ram stick at a time? If you say it does not shutdown with just ram stick in there, then the other is most likely bad.

Comment: Memtest reported 64 errors and computer shut down right after I've closed the test. Any ways of testing the power supply? Voltage seems to be OK in CPUID, but I don't know what happens the moment it shuts down.

Comment: @AnastasiaSitnina if you have 64 errors, the RAM is faulty. Test each RAM mdule on its own (remove the other) to see which is damaged.