# PC doesn't boot most of the time

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply

PC is now dismantled down to:

1. motherboard (Asus Z97AR)
2. CPU (Core i7)
3. PSU (750W)

Motherboard and CPU are new, PSU is old.

If you continuously turn the power on, then of, then on again, sometimes it proceeds to self-test and signals the absence of the RAM (which is OK - RAM was removed to exclude it from testing, since I know [there are errors too](https://superuser.com/questions/931755/computer-shuts-down-randomly-suspected-psu-or-memory-which-one-is-it/931757?noredirect=1#comment1266307_931757)), but majority of time CPU fan is turning but motherboard doesn't start the POST self-test.

What could it be? What is wrong with the faulty element?

EDT1. 
Previously (before taking it apart) checked the voltage in CPUID - it was within the norm.

EDT2.
Got it plugged in via a Surge Protector - it doesn't start the first time after the back switch was turned on, then starts every time, unless the back switch is turned off again. With other details connected gets to windows then shuts off randomly.

Comment: errr, maybe the old PSU....

Comment: Well, yes, it kinda is the first suspect, but what could be wrong with it? Is it consistent with some problem encountered before?

Comment: Obvious and probably already done, but.... Check all cables. Including the power cable from the PSU to the motherboard (and its power ok line).  Check if the PC power on it you [gently!] shake it (loose connections!).

Comment: Yes, I've checked cables, also tried disconnecting and reconnecting and now checked the connectors too - no change.

Comment: Swap in a known good (New) PSU it the only real test.